# Android doesn't work if I use mobile data instead of wifi

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, android-permissions

When I launch my android app and I try to do a login process using WiFi data, it's all right.
But if I launch the app again and I try to to the same process using mobile data, the process still waiting until I get an error.

The code is:

```
class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask< String, String, String > {
    String username, password;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        username = params[0];
        password = params[1];

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URI_login);
        post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        try {
            JSONObject jpost = new JSONObject();
            jpost.put("password", password);
            jpost.put("username", username);

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jpost.toString(),"UTF-8"); 
            entity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            entity.setContentType("application/json");

            post.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);
            resultado = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

            System.out.println("Nos llega: "+ resultado.toString() +"");

          **//UPDATE, I was returning null**
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "e-json"; //
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "e-encoding";
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "e-client";
        } **catch (IOException e) {   ***//Now, this is the error***
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "e-io";**
        }

        return resultado.toString();

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       pDialog.dismiss();
       Log.e("onPostExecute=",""+result);

       if (result.equals("ok")){
           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HiScreen.class);
           i.putExtra("user_hi", username);
           Log.e("onPostExecute= ", "Login is correct");
           login_ok();
           startActivity(i);
       }else{
            Log.e("onPostExecute= ", result);
       }
    }
```

Firstly, I thought that it would be due to permissions but I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

and then, the Logcat returns me: **[UPDATE]**

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.104:8080 refused at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183) 
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:575)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:498)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:476)
    at com.josvalbae.androidrest_1.MainActivity$AsyncLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:196)
    at com.josvalbae.androidrest_1.MainActivity$AsyncLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.104 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

I think, there is no problem with permissions.

The problem is that I don't know if is due to how long the process or other aspect.**[Timeout error]** I was looking for on the Internet but I don't have any idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code that produces the error

Comment: Depends; what's at line 266 in MainActivity.java?

Comment: @Luke I have updated it. I was returning null value so I don't know  who produces the problem. Now I see it's caused by timeout.

Comment: Are you using an emulator or a real device to test it?

Comment: @DanielMendel I am using a real device

Comment: Time out error is when a request is made but it was not answered in time, if you are saying it works with Wifi but not carrier data, so I assume maybe there is a problem with your carrier connection, maybe its too slow?

Comment: @DanielMendel I think it's unlikely because I can see videos on YouTube and listening to music with Spotify, and I think these applications consumes more data than a login process. Is it possible to be right ? In addition, I was checking the network using a sniffer network and I could see the POST method

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but are you trying to connect to 192.168.*? (asterisk used as a wildcard)

Comment: @Luke I don't understand the question. I am trying to connect  to 192.168.1.104:8080. Are you refer to this?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a localhost on the network or a real server-site?

Comment: @DanielMendel Ok, I'm trying to connect to a localhost on my private network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`192.168.*` addresses belong to private networks and therefore are not accessible from the Internet. See the article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), so called 16-bit block.

It works when you're on WiFi, because you're on the network and by typing it in, it will forward it to the router, which will serve the appropriate page (notice how request never really reaches the Internet). When on mobile data, however, there are no routers, just cell towers which don't implement this interface and you'll end up trying to look up page which doesn't exist on the Internet. The loading most probably hangs (something recognizes the address, but it can't provide the requested page) until connection times out, causing the given Exception.

Without further context, I cannot provide any solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Luke ! You have reason. I don't know how I forget it. I have the following context: My application try to connect to my web service also local. Is there any option to try the application works with mobile data, like hosting the web service on free hosting domain, or any similar?

Comment: Sure, you just need to pick one (e. g. [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/)), upload your code there and put IP or domain name in your app.

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with RedHat in any way.