# Socket connection over Mobile data

Tags: android, sockets

I'm developing an Android application that is required to send data over the Internet without using WiFi.

Is it possible to connect a socket to a server via Mobile Data?

My application works with WiFi, but doesn't work with Mobile Data.

Comment: what do you exactly mean with 'does not work with Mobile Data'? can you please share the code which causes the problem?

Comment: "Mobile Data" and "WiFi" are just different ways the device's *hardware* gains access to the Internet. Your app runs at a higher level and should be able to communicate with Internet servers using TCP or UDP normally regardless of the type of *hardware* connection being used. If you are having trouble with Mobile data, either the mobile carrier is blocking data access on its end (in which case, there's nothing your app can do, the problem is with the user's mobile account), or you are likely doing something wrong in your socket code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm guessing, but possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411855/android-doesnt-work-if-i-use-mobile-data-instead-of-wifi/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really said what's the problem, so here's a wild guess:

You're developing on a local server, on address 192.168.something.something. On your home WiFi everything works, on mobile data it can't find the server.

If so, 192.168.*.* are local addresses. They are bound to your router and requesting them never reaches the internet because they are handled locally, which is totally fine if you're connected to that router. On mobile data, however, you aren't using the router which would resolve a local address, but rather a mobile tower which has no idea what you're asking it for - it doesn't know 192.168.*.* is your computer, so you can't establish a connection.

For the most part, transmitting data over WiFi and mobile data should make no difference. If there is, the problem is probably somewhere else. So here, in order to make it work with mobile data you need an actual remote server (which could be hosted on your computer if your ISP allows that, but that's another topic).

You do need to provide a better explanation for your problem - what address you are accessing and what's the error? I only have this hunch (and I'm quite confident in it) because I have at least one more answer with identical solution somewhere on the site (and the question was quite similar), which means you probably could've found it using Google (edit: yup, [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411855/android-doesnt-work-if-i-use-mobile-data-instead-of-wifi/32413089#32413089)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm currently using a local address to run my server. So what's the best way to get a public ip? I mean, is there a way to get a public server for free or do i need to pay monthly? @Luke

Comment: Is there a way to redirect the connections of my public ip addres to the address of my server? @Luke

Comment: @AndreaPasin not really, look up setting up a remote webserver online. There are various online hosts, depending on what are you doing - there's plethora free php hostings. If you need actual access to the machine (e.g. ssh), you could try Openshift's free plan or pay for something like DigitalOcean, Bluehost or such. It is possible to set up a server on your local machine, but you'll have to handle network configuration yourself, and honestly I don't know how to do this and whether your ISP will have anything against it

Comment: I know this question is old. But @Luke your comment is wrong. You certainly can use your public ip. You will need to set up port forwarding on the router which does NAT (usually called the internet box). You just have to forward the external port to the ip:port of your home server.